# When load ASPX page into div, code behind method wont fired

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

```
$("#test").click(function () {
    $("#panelToLoad").load("Test.aspx", function () {
    })
});
```

When I load a page into div like this. An event like mouse on that page won't fire.

Load page method is fired.

Comment: are you triggering it inside $(document).ready(..) ???

Comment: Are you getting any error in browser's dev console (F12/Ctrl-Shift-J to see them)? You can expand `load` like this: `$("#panelToLoad").load("Test.aspx", function (response, status, xhr) {  alert(response + " " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText); })` and see what messages are returned in alert box.

Comment: Page is load normally. Page load method if fired but method for button click won't fired

Comment: Try .on in jquery to bind a listener

Answer (score 0):

Page load wont get fired until your button clicked is not triggered. Is your control id correct or is this event called inside document.ready?